# How do I exclude one specific form of several from my Google Analytics form fills Goal Conversion tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, event-tracking, goals, analytics-events

I have lots of contact forms on my site. All of them could lead to paying customers except one — the form on the hiring page. I want to track all of the form fills as goal conversions for all of the pages EXCEPT for the `https://example.com/jobs/` page.

This seems like it should be an extremely common problem, but I've searched and searched the Internets for an answer to this, all to no avail. Anybody want to break the news to me that I've foolishly overlooked some extremely simple menu option somewhere? Or is the answer more involved?

**Details of current setup**: Admin > Goals > + New goal > Goal setup - Custom > Goal description - Event > Goal details - Category Equals to forms, Action Equals to submit, Label Equals to contact, Value Greater than ___

**Summary**: How can I exclude the hiring page form fills from my Google Analytics conversion tracking?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the reason I wasn't finding my answer from "Googling" it is that my solution should be found by making a change to my site, not to changing Google Analytics setup.

I use Contact Form 7, and this page https://contactform7.com/tracking-form-submissions-with-google-analytics/ seems to indicate that I have to get rid of the Contact Form 7 event listener from the header of that particular page.